# Cannot lock a c++ 11 std::mutex on a DLL

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, mutex

I'm trying to prevent multiple calls to a DLL initialization function by using a std::lock object.

While using a program like this on a stand alone program works:

```
#include <mutex>
std::mutex mtx;

void main(){
  mtx.lock();
  (...)
  mtx.unlock()
}
```

This exact same code cannot get past the *mtx.lock()* when called on a DLL.

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule,
    DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
    LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    f_Init(VERSION_ID);
    return TRUE;
}

//On another cpp file, a static library actually.
#include <mutex>
std::mutex mutex_state;
void f_Init(DWORD version){
    //Acquire the state lock
    mutex_state.lock(); //<-- Will NOT get past this line
    (...)
    mutex_state.unlock();
}
```

Why is it imposible to lock the mutex on this situation?

I'm currently using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Yes, pretty much the same question. Also, if D Schwartz (below) is right, the lock on the DLLMAIN is not needed.

Comment: For reference, Microsoft Connect [bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/809005/deadlock-when-locking-std-mutex-during-dllmain-static-initialization) that was closed as *by design*.

Comment: What does your actual initialization consist of? Most likely, it's things that should not be done in `DllMain`. (See [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/27/63401.aspx) for why `DllMain` should be minimal.)

Answer (score 0):

The mutex is not needed. Access to `DllMain` is serialized by the implementation.

> Access to the entry point is serialized by the system on a process-wide basis. Threads in DllMain hold the loader lock so no additional DLLs can be dynamically loaded or initialized. -- [DllMain Entry Point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Your code deadlocks deadlock when you enter `DllMain` because you already hold locks. Trying to acquire additional locks while holding some unknown combination of locks is very, very likely to deadlock. You should *never* acquire any additional locks inside `DllMain`.

Consider, for example, if some additional DLL needs to be attached to lock the mutex. Two DLL's cannot be attached at the same time, and your DLL is being attached. Locking a mutex for the first time may require allocating memory and allocating memory may require attaching DLL's -- so don't do that in DllMain.

By the way, these same painful restrictions apply to constructors and destructors for global objects.