# Qt/C++ application stucks before main() starts when using singleton from DLL

Tags: c++, qt, program-entry-point, freeze

We have a Qt-based application.

Today I was working on extracting of some resources and code into separate DLL.

As soon as I start using DLL instead of the local classes, I got very strange behavior:

**Application gets stuck even BEFORE hitting main() function.**

Does anybody has ANY idea what might be wrong?
I don't know where to dig, so don't know what's relevant here.

We are using cmake 3.4 to configure project, Qt 5.4, Visual Studio 2012.

**UPDATE.** According to VS output application starts and successfully loads all the dlls. So I can see the console window, which is empty.

**UPDATE 2.** @Martin James, almost the right answer. The problem was in a singleton initialization, which used mutex. I don't understand completely why, but it stucks on mutex if called during DLL loading.

**UPDATE 3.** In a kind of way it's a duplicate of [C++11 std::mutex in Visual Studio 2012 deadlock when locked from DllMain()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711263/c11-stdmutex-in-visual-studio-2012-deadlock-when-locked-from-dllmain). When asking the question, the reason of the lock was unknown.

Comment: You won't get any meaningful help without showing your source code and/or some MVCE

Comment: Believe me, I'd like to show some code, but what do you want to see? cmake scripts, main function? The thing is, that I don't know what can cause such a behaviour, that's why I cannot provide an example.

Comment: Make sure Qt and all other dependencies were built with the same version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes, all the dependencies (including Qt and other third-parties) are built for MSVC 2012 x64

Comment: Did you try to clean every object file and rebuild entirely from fresh source code?

Comment: Absolutely, that was the first thing I tried, considering I was moving code around and some obj files are incorrect.

Comment: Well, if `main` isn't executed, then it's not _your app_ that's freezing/getting stuck.

Comment: @ForceBru, well the only thing I see is the empty console window and VS output shows that it was able to load all the dll-s, including the new one. Then I just don't understand what stucks.

Comment: @Werolik, then either use the debugger or put some `cout` printing to see where exactly the problem appears.

Comment: @ForceBru, I cannot debug, because it stucks BEFORE main is executed.

Comment: Have you tried profiling your program with Dependency Walker ? It might discover issues related to DLL loading.

Comment: No, may be indeed a good idea, trying that now.

Comment: @ForceBru static ctors run before main() and bugs there can prevent main() executing, (I know, I've done it often enough:).

Comment: @MartinJames, you were almost correct, see update 2.

Comment: lol, singleton poisoning;)

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/809005/deadlock-when-locking-std-mutex-during-dllmain-static-initialization

Comment: @MartinJames, add it as an answer, please.

Comment: TBH, it's more like a duplicate than an answer:)

Comment: Yeah, considering, that you pointed in right direction this is the answer. Tnx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attempting to explicitly prevent multiple access in DLL initialization with a mutex can result in deadlock for reasons best known to MS:(

[Cannot lock a c++ 11 std::mutex on a DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24601501/cannot-lock-a-c-11-stdmutex-on-a-dll)
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/809005/deadlock-when-locking-std-mutex-during-dllmain-static-initialization